# passing php value as parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to pass php variable as parameter in onblur event.2nd parameter is not passed to the function.
Here I attached my code.

```
echo "<p>Email<input type=text name=email id=email size=18 maxlength=50 required onblur='javascript:myFunction(this.value,".$fet['email'].");' value='".$email."' ></p>";
```

script

```
       <script>
         function myFunction(em,a) {
         alert(a);
       if(em!='')
      {     
     var x = document.forms["profile"]["email"].value;
     var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
     var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
     if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
     alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
     document.getElementById("email").value = "";
     return false;
     exit();
     }
         }                }
       </script>
```

Comment: if is a string don't you need to use a single or double quote?

Comment: Its a string.so I need to use  quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `double quotes` around second parameter (there is already singles quote to call js).
So try this:

```
echo "<p>Email<input onblur='javascript:myFunction(this.value,\"".$fet['email']."\");' value='".$email."' ></p>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add single quotes around your second parameter.

Corrected code:

```
echo "<p>Email<input type=text name=email id=email size=18 maxlength=50 required onblur='javascript:myFunction(this.value,\'".$fet['email']."\');' value='".$email."' ></p>";
```

Otherwise, javascript will consider your argument as a keyword like `this`.

Comment: some quotes is missing